# Formula calculations in Java

Tags: java, excel, math, apache-commons-math

I do have mathematical formulas like,

> (3.14*2.500^2)/4
>
> IF(45.0=0,0,1/42.9^2)

Which are formulas derived from Excel formulas.

I need to get result of these kind of formulas using java only.

I come across [helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7258671/1230360).

Can you please advice me for best way doing this?

1. **Do we have anything where we can directly put this formula and get result?**
2. **Do I need to Tokanize the string and calculate it using basic Java Math package?**
3. **If I have to Tokanize only then which is the best basic Math package or Commons Math?**

Comment: Why negative? Any reason?

Comment: possible duplicate of [free Java library for evaluating math expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258538/free-java-library-for-evaluating-math-expressions)

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert spreadsheet formulas to java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043614/convert-spreadsheet-formulas-to-java)

Comment: start by writing in java if is lower case.  I usually write out my if statements so I can see the indentations.  if(a=45){b=0;} else {b = 90;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No. Java and most other languages does not have a function to evaluate an expression from a string.

2-3) Yes. You must tokenize it and write your own parser, or just use a library, like the one you posted the link.

Comment: Yes JEval is really a great library and same had resolved my requirements.